# Inverse regression procedures with robust linear models, quantile regression, and machine learning methods

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, prediction

*Context*

Often in dose-response models we regress some range of doses against a response variable, but we are really interested in identifying the dose required to elicit a particular response. Typically this is done with inverse regression techniques (i.e. [after-fitting / reparameterisation](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0146021)). EDIT: To clarify -  this is commonly done when you need to estimate the dose required to kill say 50%, or 99.99% for quarantine protocols. To derive these estimates people employ inverse regression techniques - the above link goes through this more carefully (see page 9).

*Question*

How can I carry out these inverse regression procedures using methods like robust linear models, quantile regression, or machine learning models (i.e.  neural networks or support vector machines)? EDIT: To clarify, I want a programming solution to how I can estimate the dose required to elicit a response of 99.99 when the model I have fitted is one of the above mentioned. I have fitted example models below to these ends.

My data looks like this:

```
  df <- structure(list(Response = c(100, 91.1242603550296, 86.9822485207101, 
100, 0, 0, 90.5325443786982, 95.8579881656805, 88.7573964497041, 
96.4497041420118, 82.2485207100592, 99.4082840236686, 99.4082840236686, 
98.8165680473373, 91.7159763313609, 59.1715976331361, 44.9704142011834, 
0, 100, 95.2662721893491, 100, 82.8402366863905, 7.69230769230769, 
81.6568047337278, 62.7218934911243, 97.6331360946746, 73.9644970414201, 
8.87573964497041, 0, 98.8165680473373, 78.1065088757396, 98.2248520710059, 
52.6627218934911, 96.4497041420118, 52.0710059171598, 0, 62.043795620438, 
84.6715328467153, 97.8102189781022, 4.37956204379562, 89.051094890511, 
99.2700729927007, 99.2700729927007, 97.0802919708029, 81.7518248175183, 
80.2919708029197, 90.5109489051095, 99.2700729927007, 96.3503649635037, 
0, 0, 94.8905109489051, 79.5620437956204, 67.8832116788321, 73.7226277372263, 
100, 97.0802919708029, 93.4306569343066, 86.8613138686131, 33.5766423357664, 
32.1167883211679, 46.7153284671533, 98.5401459854015, 95.6204379562044, 
86.1313868613139, 14.5985401459854, 92.7007299270073, 86.1313868613139, 
0, 77.3722627737226, 89.051094890511, 80.2919708029197, 98.1818181818182, 
96.3636363636364, 30.9090909090909, 0, 60.9090909090909, 100, 
0, 83.6363636363636, 88.1818181818182, 97.2727272727273, 0, 0, 
99.0909090909091, 100, 100, 91.8181818181818, 88.1818181818182, 
46.3636363636364, 50.9090909090909, 99.0909090909091, 97.2727272727273, 
100, 0, 92.7272727272727, 60.9090909090909, 90.9090909090909, 
57.2727272727273, 76.3636363636364, 94.5454545454545, 50, 98.1818181818182, 
16.3636363636364, 87.2727272727273, 92.7272727272727, 87.2727272727273, 
88.1818181818182, 10.7438016528926, 91.7355371900827, 98.3471074380165, 
60.3305785123967, 95.8677685950413, 0, 63.6363636363636, 71.900826446281, 
0, 74.3801652892562, 76.8595041322314, 0, 61.9834710743802, 0, 
0, 0, 84.297520661157, 47.1074380165289, 69.4214876033058, 97.5206611570248, 
100, 61.1570247933884, 90.0826446280992, 78.5123966942149, 10.7438016528926, 
100, 98.3471074380165, 100, 98.3471074380165, 93.3884297520661, 
90.9090909090909, 57.8512396694215, 57.8512396694215, 92.5619834710744, 
77.6859504132231, 69.4214876033058), Covariate = c(20, 14, 14, 
20, 0, 0, 14, 14, 14, 16, 10, 20, 20, 20, 16, 10, 10, 0, 16, 
16, 16, 10, 0, 12, 10, 12, 12, 0, 0, 20, 12, 16, 10, 12, 12, 
0, 14, 14, 16, 0, 14, 20, 16, 20, 14, 12, 12, 20, 20, 0, 0, 14, 
12, 10, 10, 20, 16, 16, 14, 10, 10, 10, 20, 16, 10, 0, 12, 12, 
0, 12, 16, 14, 16, 14, 0, 0, 12, 20, 0, 12, 14, 14, 0, 0, 20, 
20, 20, 14, 14, 10, 10, 20, 16, 16, 0, 12, 10, 10, 10, 16, 16, 
12, 20, 10, 12, 12, 16, 14, 0, 16, 20, 12, 14, 10, 10, 0, 0, 
12, 12, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 14, 12, 12, 20, 20, 14, 14, 14, 12, 
20, 20, 20, 16, 16, 14, 10, 10, 16, 16, 16)), row.names = 433:576, class = "data.frame")
```

with my formula usually being something like:

Response ~ Covariate + I(Covariate^2)

Here is an example of the models I have fitted:

```
#Robust linear model
MASS::rlm(Response ~ Covariate + I(Covariate^2), data = df)

#Quantile regression
quantreg::rq(Response ~ Covariate + I(Covariate^2), data = df, tau = c(0.5, 0.95)) # In this case I want to predict the specified quantiles for the dose required to elicit a given response, although I realised this code doesn't do that...

#Machine learning algorithms were trained with caret
TRControl <- trainControl(method = "cv")

#Neural Network
caret::train(Response  ~ Covariate, data = df, method = "neuralnet", trControl = TRControl)

#Support Vector Machine
caret::train(Response  ~ Covariate, data = df, method = "polySVM", trControl = TRControl)
```

Comment: This sounds like more of a statistics question than a programming one. If so, this would be a better fit for [stats.se]

Comment: It does sit on the boundary... I put it here as I am looking for a programming solution having assumed it is not a novel concept. Happy to migrate it if need be.

Comment: *"interested in identifying the dose required to elicit a particular response"* I'm not really sure I understand what you're asking. Usually one would fit a *parametric* (dose-response) model to the data which would allow you to directly obtain an estimate of e.g. the dose necessary for a 50% reduction of the response quantity (the IC50 value); so I'm not sure why you want to employ "inverse regression techniques". The dose-response model will allow you to determine concentrations that "elicit" any specific response.

Comment: I have tried to clarify my question above; hopefully it is more clear what I am asking but please feel free to ask if anything still doesn't make sense. @MauritsEvers my understanding from the paper attached to my question is that an inverse regression technique is always required - in quarantine research Fieller's formula is usually used to these ends to calculate an interval for the estimate. How do you "directly obtain an estimate of e.g. the dose necessary for a 50% reduction of the response quantity (the IC50 value)"?

Comment: At the very least you need to read `?formula` so that you can understand why all your formulas will fail to deliver what you expect. I also question whether you know what you are doing with the last two (and maybe the last three)  methods. I don't think formulas make any sense in those contexts.

Comment: @André.B *"an inverse regression technique is always required"* I don't get that from the paper at all (but perhaps I'm misunderstanding your objective goal). Generally, you'd fit a dose-response model (say a three-parameter log-logistic model of the type `drc::LL.3`) to your dose response data. In this example, the three parameters correspond to an offset parameter, the IC50 value and a slope parameter characterising the "steepness" of the sigmoidal dose-response curve. Fitting the model to the data gives you the full dose-response curve, including an estimate (plus CI) for the IC50 value.

Comment: [continued] That's a fairly standard procedure for estimating IC50 values from dose response measurements. There's no need for any inverse regression technique, just a simple non-linear model fit.

Comment: @42- I think I found the mistake you alluded to in my formulas (hopefully). Could you expand on "I also question whether you know what you are doing with the last two (and maybe the last three) methods. I don't think formulas make any sense in those contexts." please?

Comment: @MauritsEvers what is more likely is that I have misunderstood the authors of the attached paper - This post was started by these sentences: *"Estimating doses corresponding to specific response levels is often of particular interest in dose-response analysis. Such estimates are obtained by solving an inverse regression problem, which may be approached either through after-fitting or re-parameterization."* - What I wanted was code to calculate LD99's using SVMs,  quantile regression and robust linear models.... Is this wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I know this post was quite unclear - I am still trying to get my head around it.

Comment: I don't think formulas with polynomial terms make much sense in the context of SVM's. I suppose I could be wrong, but can you point to a good reference that shows such a use?

Comment: @André.B Not knowing the specifics of your objective, I would start by fitting a sensible (non-linear) dose-response model to your data using `drc`. Once you have your fitted model, it's straightforward to determine the LD99 from the fitted model. Similarly to what 42- pointed out, I don't think the (linear) models you defined above don't make much sense in the context of dose response measurements.

Comment: @42- It probably doesn't make any sense and I will drop these terms now.

Comment: @MauritsEvers the goal of the exercise is I would like to compare the performance of each of these models at determining the dose required to elicit a given response. I.e. I want to see which model gets closest to a known value. To do that I need to have them calculate a LD estimate.

Comment: @André.B Well as I suggested, I would fit different `drc` models to your data, which will allow you to extract the LD estimates which you can then compare. Having said that, having taken a look at the data you posted, they don't really look like typical dose-response data.

Comment: @MauritsEvers I know the data looks horrible but trust me - it is dose-response. It has just been heavily edited and it was poor to begin with. I am not really interested in the `drc` models unfortunately; the aim is to derive estimates from the models that I mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further to my comments above, your data doesn't really resemble that of a typical dose-response measurement

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(Covariate, log10(Response))) +
    geom_point()
```

[image]

Here I assume that `Covariate` is the dose/concentration.

Do the different measurements for every `Covariate` relate to different experiments/groups? Do you plan on fitting multiple dose response curves do different groups in order to compare them?

---

### A possible analysis strategy

Here is something that might give you some ideas. I'm using `drc` here because it allows me to fit a "sensible" dose-response curve to your data. A sensible dose-response model has horizontal asymptotes for `dose → 0` and `dose → ∞`.

1. In this particular example we fit a four parameter Weibull function to your data.

   ```
   library(drc)
   model <- drm(Response ~ Covariate, data = df, fct = W2.4())
   ```
2. Let's plot original data and model predictions (including confidence interval)

   ```
   library(tidyverse)
   df.pred <- data.frame(Covariate = 1.1 * seq(min(df$Covariate), max(df$Covariate), length.out = 20)) %>%
       bind_cols(as.data.frame(predict(model, data.frame(Covariate = Covariate), interval = "confidence"))) %>%
       rename(Response = Prediction)

   ggplot(df, aes(Covariate, Response)) +
       geom_point() +
       geom_line(data = df.pred, aes(Covariate, Response), color = "blue") +
       geom_ribbon(data = df.pred, aes(x = Covariate, ymin = Lower, ymax = Upper), fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2)
   ```

   [image]
3. We can now use `uniroot` to determine specific LDx values, which are defined as the dose required to reduce the maximum response by `x` / 100.

   ```
   getLDx <- function(model, x = 0.5) {
       maxResponse <- max(predict(model, data.frame(x = c(0, Inf))))
       uniroot(
           function(Covariate) predict(model, newdata = data.frame(Covariate = Covariate)) - x * maxResponse,
           interval = range(Covariate))$root
   }
   ```

   This is basically an inversion of the model, so perhaps this is what the authors of the papers you link to in your original post refer to as "inverse regression techniques".
4. Let's calculate the LD50 value (i.e. the dose required to reduce the response by 50%)

   ```
   getLDx(model, x = 0.5)
   #[1] 9.465188
   ```

   From an inspection of the plot you can see that this value indeed corresponds to the dose where the response is 50% of the maximum response value.

Comment: I know this is not typical - it is the only one my company would let me release online. Each value of the covariate is the dosage the subjects received.

Comment: @André.B Ok, from a statistical modelling point of view I'd say there is little you can do here. I can guarantee that any model fit will be poor given the subject variability you have at specific doses. In other words, you could fit anything to the data, resulting estimates would have large uncertainties, making it hard to decide on any one model being the "best" model.

Comment: I understand, but fortunately this is not the data that I will actually be working with - just the only data that I was allowed to release (probably for the reasons you mentioned). Honestly, thank you for engaging with my question and putting in the effort to understand it! I know that tone can be lost in text based discussions, but I really do appreciate the help.

Comment: You're very welcome @André.B; it's an interesting discussion. In my line of work (biomedical drug efficacy studies) dose response analyses are commonly done along the lines of what's described in the `drc` paper which is therefore what I'm most familiar with. In any case, I wish you good luck with your further explorations.

Comment: @André.B I've added a possible analysis strategy that may give you some ideas on how to proceed.

Comment: It has taken me awhile to get back around to this, but when I have just tried running the code you provided and I have been getting the following error: `Error in uniroot(function(Covariate) predict(model, newdata = data.frame(Covariate = Covariate)) -  : 
  object 'Covariate' not found` - Any ideas? The model fit and the `getLDx` call was that same you provided.

Comment: I think I figured it out: getLDx <- function(model, Covariate, x = 0.5) {
  maxResponse <- max(predict(model, data.frame(x = c(0, Inf))))
  uniroot(
    function(Covariate) predict(model, newdata = data.frame(Covariate = Covariate)) - x * maxResponse,
    interval = range(Covariate))$root
}